# Characterization of linear differential operators in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering exactly how to characterize a ***linear*** differential operators in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Some lecture notes on the internet told me that a differential operator of order $m$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is an operator of the form
$$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq m}f_\alpha(x_1,\ldots,x_n) D^\alpha,\tag{$*$}$$
where $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$, $D^\alpha=\partial_{x_1}^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial_{x_n}^{\alpha_n}$, and the coefficient function $f_\alpha$ with $|\alpha|=m$ is nonvanishing. Clearly, this operator is linear. **How about the converse?** Is it **always** possible to write any linear differential operator in the form of $(*)$?

A fundamential theorem in linear algebra says that for **each** linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, there exists a unique matrix $A$ such that $T=L_A$ with $L_A$ denoting the left-multiplication $x\mapsto Ax$. Can we draw an analogy for linear differential operators as above? Thank you.

**Added:** According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator), a differential operator is defined as a function of the differentiation operator, and there are linear differential operators plus nonlinear differential operators. For example, [the Schwarzian derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzian_derivative) is a nonlinear differential operator. Confusingly, though, the article in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_operator) later defines a differential operator by using $(*)$. In this case, how can one talk about nonlinear operators?

Comment: What’s the definition of a linear differential operator that you are starting with?

Comment: Sorry, that's where my problem comes from. I don't have a reference that clearly defines what a differential operator is like. A lecture note I found simply adopts $(*)$ as a definition; that way, we wouldn't have nonlinear differential operators.

Comment: (*) is the standard definition of a linear differential operator. In some contexts the word linear might be omitted because in some contexts the word operator implies linear.

Comment: @Deane Thank you, but why don't we define linearity of a differential operator $L$ in such a way that $L(kf+g)=kL(f)+L(g)$, as we do for linear transformations between **vector spaces**? This incorporates $(*)$ as a special case, leading to the discussion just before the **Added** part.

Comment: I don’t understand. Implicit in (*) is the fact that the operator is linear. But a linear operator isn’t necessarily a linear differential operator. So if you want something to imply (*), you have to assume something additional about the linear operator. It’s possible to manufacture assumptions that imply (*) but in the end,  (*) is the simplest and most direct way to define a linear differential operator.

Comment: @Deane I'm very grateful for your help. Thank you. I was wondering if there exists a differential operator $L$ that satisfies $L(kf+g)=kL(f)+L(g)$ but does NOT satisfy $(*)$.